# Matplotlib End-to-end chart plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting the following graph using this code and all of a sudden it now leaves these gaps at the beginning and end of the graph.  What gives? How can I make this graph stretch end to end of my data?

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 10))

plt.plot(model_output['A'].cumsum())

plt.plot(model_output['B'].cumsum())

plt.plot(model_output['C'].cumsum())

plt.plot(model_output['D'].cumsum())

plt.yticks(fontsize=(15))
plt.xticks(fontsize=(15))
plt.xlabel("")
return model_output, plt
```

[image]

Comment: `ax = plt.gca(); ax.set_xlim([minval, maxval])`

Comment: Lord bless your soul, Paul H.

Comment: Note that because you may not know the limits before plotting, it would be better to use `ax.margins(0)` instead of `set_xlim`. Since this question has been asked already several times, I marked it as duplicate.